# How to create postgres table with JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Latest release of `PostgreSQL` have capabilities to work like document oriented databases (e.g. `MongoDB`). There Is promising benchmarks that says postgres x times faster then mongo. Can someone give me advice how to work with postgres as with `MongoDB`. I'm seeking for step by step simple example concerned on

1) How to create simpliest table that contain JSON/JSONB objects like documents in mongodb

2) How to make search on it at least by `id`, like I can do in `mongodb` with `collection.find({id: 'objectId'})` for example

3) How to create new object or overwrite existing at least by `id`, like I can do in `mongodb` with

```
 collection.update(
     {id: objectId},
     {$set: someSetObject, $unset: someUnsetObject}
     {upsert: true, w: 1}
  )
```

4) How to delete object if it exists at leas by `id`, like I can do in `mongodb` with `collection.remove({id: 'objectId'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too large topic to be covered in one answer. So there is just some examples as requested. For more information see documentation:

- [8.14. JSON Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)
- [9.15. JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Create table:

```
create table test(
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb);
```

Search by id:

```
select * from test where id = 1;
```

Search by json value:

```
select * from test where data->>'a' = '1';
```

Insert and update data:

```
insert into test(id, data) values (1, '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}');
update test set data = data - 'a' || '{"c": 5}' where id = 1;
```

Delete data by id:

```
delete from test where id = 1;
```

Delete data by json value:

```
delete from test where data->>'b' = '2';
```

Comment: You may have a mistake in your answer: JSON operator `->` returns JSON. To return a JSON element for comparison you need to use `->>`. Example `data->>'a' = '1'`

Comment: You probably right. `->` returns jsonb and `->>` returns text. But it's not clear to me which one better to use for comparison. Anyway both variants works.

Comment: It turns out that it can be a little tricky to search by text value with `->` operator: `where data->>'a' = 'test'` vs. `where data->'a' = '"test"'` (we have to use double quotes to make it convertible to jsnob). So I updated answer.